# Why this typescript code works. { [key: string]: string }[] vs { prop1: string, prop2: string }[]

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
  get tags(): { [key: string]: string }[] {
    let tags: { [key: string]: string }[] = [];

    if(this.tags) {
      Object.keys(this.tags).forEach(x => {
        tags.push({ prop1: this.tags[x], prop2: getVal(x)});
      });
    }
    return tags;
  }
```

I would expect that return type would mismatch but it is not. Can you explain why it is works?

Is it better to write the following code instead?

```
      get tags(): { prop1: string, prop2: string }[] {
        let tags: { prop1: string, prop2: string }[] = [];
    
        if(this.tags) {
          Object.keys(this.tags).forEach(x => {
            tags.push({ prop1: this.tags[x], prop2: getVal(x)});
          });
        }
        return tags;
      }
```

Comment: *Why* would you expect a type mismatch? You are telling the compile you have types, with arbitrary keys, but all values have to be `string`s. And there is nothing that violates that rule ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below are called [Index Signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

```
{ [key: string]: string }[]
```

They are used when you do not know the names of all the keys that an object type will have. So you tell Typescript that although the name of the key is not known above hand you know that the value will be of type `string`. All keys are always strings anyways.

So typescript does not complain for the first snippet.

The 2nd question is more opinion based, but since it looks like you will only have two keys ever in your code `prop1` and `prop2`, better to have a stricter check so no other developer can come and add a `prop3` (which they can do with the first piece of code).